# Dynamically adding series

Tags: javascript, time-series, dygraphs, multiple-axes

I am trying to dynamically add series and axes to a line plot.
I am trying to use a call-back function to allocate series. But am having trouble with the syntax :

```
series: function() {
        return {
          'Level 1': {
            axis: 'y2'
          }
        }
      },
```

Any examples of how this can be achieved?

Comment: Is there call-back support for this ?

Answer (score 1):

dygraphs doesn't support callbacks that way. You'll want to use [`updateOptions`](http://dygraphs.com/jsdoc/symbols/Dygraph.html#updateOptions) with the [`file`](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#file) parameter. See [this example](http://dygraphs.com/1.1.1/tests/linear-regression-addseries.html).